# amqp assertQueue bork a connection meaning

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

In  amqp's assertQueue API Documentation, it states:

*Assert a queue into existence. This operation is idempotent given identical arguments; however, it will bork the channel if the queue already exists but has different properties (values supplied in the arguments field may or may not count for borking purposes; check the borker's, I mean broker's, documentation).*

http://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/channel_api.html#channel_assertQueue

I am asking what it means by bork(ing) the channel. I tried google but can't find anything relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try calling `assertQueue` twice, with different properties the second time? You would have answered your own question very quickly.

I used [this code](https://github.com/squaremo/amqp.node/blob/master/examples/tutorials/send.js) to create this test program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var amqp = require('amqplib');

amqp.connect('amqp://localhost').then(function(conn) {
  return conn.createChannel().then(function(ch) {
    var q = 'hello';
    var ok0 = ch.assertQueue(q, {durable: false});
    return ok0.then(function(_qok) {
        var ok1 = ch.assertQueue(q, {durable: true});
        return ok1.then(function(got) {
            console.log(" [x] got '%s'", got);
            return ch.close();
        });
    });
  }).finally(function() { conn.close(); });
}).catch(console.warn);
```

Then, start RabbitMQ and run your test code. You should see output like this:

```
$ node examples/tutorials/assert-borked.js
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Channel closed by server: 406 (PRECONDITION-FAILED) with message "PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'durable' for queue 'hello' in vhost '/': received 'true' but current is 'false'"
    at Channel.C.accept
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, actually. What does "bork" mean?

Answer (score 7):

Bork: English meaning is to obstruct something.

As per the documentation in the question, it says

> however, it will bork the channel if the queue already exists but has
> different properties

this means if you try to create a channel which has the same properties of a channel which already exits, nothing would happen cause it is [idempotent](https://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/idempotency.html) (meaning repeating the same action with no different result, e.g. a REST API GET request which fetches data for id say 123, will return the same data every time unless updated, a pretty funny video explaining the impotent concept), but if you try to create a channel with the same name but different properties, the channel creation shall be "borked" i.e. obstructed.

In the code below, we create the channel again,

```
 var ok0 = ch.assertQueue(q, {durable: false});// creating the first time
 var ok1 = ch.assertQueue(q, {durable: true});// creating the second time again with different durable property value
```

it **throws an error**

> "PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'durable' for queue 'hello' in
> vhost '/': received 'true' but current is 'false'"

This means the you are trying to make the same channel with different properties, i.e. the durable property is different to the existing channel and hence it has been borked.

[2]: Answer by @Like Bakken

Comment: Brilliant answer! This should be the accepted answer since it, unlike the currently accepted answer, actually answers the question asked by the OP. On a side note, I appreciate humor in the generally humorless realm of technical documentation, but in this instance it has actually derailed me from coding since I'm having to look up a term that doesn't really bring any value to the documentation.

Comment: What is missing in this answer is: if one catches the error generated by the second assertion, will the queue go on working as it did or we will see some side-effects?